# MySQL C++ Connector always outputs the same string

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I am trying to write a program to output a row from a MYSQL table and it always outputs the same thing...
The function takes input from another function

C++

```
try {
    sql::Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;
    sql::Statement *stmt;
    sql::ResultSet *res;

/* Create a connection */
driver = get_driver_instance();
con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "TSA!");
/* Connect to the MySQL test database */
con->setSchema("main");

stmt = con->createStatement();
stmt->execute("CALL getData('" + quest1 +"', @ans)");
res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT @ans AS _message");
while (res->next()) {
    cout << "Answer: ";
    /* Access column data by alias or column name */
    cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
}
delete res;
delete stmt;
delete con;
}
```

and then a error statement which is not triggered by this program.

MySQL

```
   CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getData`(IN info MEDIUMTEXT,
OUT datas MEDIUMTEXT)
BEGIN
    SELECT `answer` from `approved` WHERE `Question` = info into datas;
END
```

The table:
question | answer
test | test
test2 | test2

The program always and only outputs "test"
How do I fix this?

Comment: please output : `cout << quest1 ;` as well to check what is param you send.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by getting a char from the user for input using `cin.getline` rather than `cin` to a string.

You can clear the existing buffer with `cin` which I believe was the problem.